# split txt file in half based on pattern

Tags: bash, text-processing, split

I have a text file which looks like this:

```
train/a/abbey/00000001.jpg 0
...
train/a/abbey/00000999.jpg 0
train/a/abbey/00001000.jpg 0
train/a/airport_terminal/00000001.jpg 1
train/a/airport_terminal/00000002.jpg 1
...
train/c/corn_field/00000354.jpg 40
train/c/corn_field/00000355.jpg 40
train/c/corn_field/00000356.jpg 40
...
train/y/yard/00000998.jpg 99
train/y/yard/00000999.jpg 99
train/y/yard/00001000.jpg 99
```

The last number in each line is the category. I have 100 categories (0 to 99) and each one contains 1,000 lines (so 100 * 1,000 = 100,000 lines in total).

I'd like to split this file into two *random* halves i.e. one half contains 50 random categories and the other half contains the other 50 categories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one does it that way, it shuffles each chapter and takes "lineswanted" lines from the result to finaly store it in the both half files:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

lineswanted=300
infile="full"
half1="half1"
half2="half2"

# Build chapterlist 0 1 2 3 ....
chapterlist=""
for (( i=0 ; i<100; i=i+1 )) ; do
  chapterlist="$chapterlist $i"
done

# shuffle chapterlist
randomchapterlist="`shuf -e $chapterlist`"

rm -f "$half1" "$half2"

i=0
for chapter in $randomchapterlist ; do
  if [ $i -lt 50 ] ; then
    egrep ".*\ $chapter\$" "$infile" | shuf | head -n $lineswanted >> "$half1"
  else
    egrep ".*\ $chapter\$" "$infile" | shuf | head -n $lineswanted >> "$half2"
  fi
  i=$(( i+1 ));
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow steps below to get your work done:

1. First of all, split this file into 100 categories files with using:

   ```
   sed -n '0,99p' file >> 1.txt
   ```

for the first category.

2. Now you have 100 files: 1.txt, 2.txt, ...., 100.txt. Each of these files has 1000 lines. you can select a line from these files randomly by following command and put in **firsthalf.txt** and **secondhalf.txt**:

   ```
   shuf -n 1 filename
   ```
3. In each of above steps you can use loops to improve your speed.

Answer (score 1):

This script should do it. In the both half files, the chapter lines are sorted as in the input file but the chapters itself are shuffled. If you need. I can extend the script to sort the chapters in each half or shuffle the lines of all chapter in one file, too.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Build chapterlist 0 1 2 3 ....
chapterlist=""
for (( i=0 ; i<100; i=i+1 )) ; do
  chapterlist="$chapterlist $i"
done

# shuffle chapterlist
randomchapterlist="`shuf -e $chapterlist`"

# "full" is input file
# half1 and half2 are output files
rm -f half1 half2

i=0
for chapter in $randomchapterlist ; do
  if [ $i -lt 50 ] ; then
    egrep ".*\ $chapter\$" full >> half1
  else
    egrep ".*\ $chapter\$" full >> half2
  fi
  i=$(( i+1 ));
done
```

Comment: Genius, efficient script! The  original order within the chapters is fine, thank you! However, can I ask for another extension? Let's say I want to (again) randomly select from each chapter N amount of lines. For example, now I have 1,000 lines per chapter. But what if I want, 500, or 300? Do you know how to reach this objective? Thanks again!